# Want to chage the Slider Tick color and style

Tags: wpf, controls

I don't want to change the whole template of slider just want to change the Ticks and track of slider.

I want the Track Bar appearance should be like this:

the background color of the slider must be black , the color of the track must be gray and the color of the picks must also be gray.

How to do this task?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please clarify by providing some code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

first simple solution without res-styling the slider

```
<Slider
  Width="200"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Background="Black"
  Foreground="Gray"
  Maximum="100"
  Minimum="0"
  TickPlacement="BottomRight"
  Ticks="0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100"
  Value="20"/>
```

[image]

Comment: @user3034952 Based on the exact wording of your question, the suggestion from @punker76 is the right solution. You may want to mark it as an `Answer` so others (including myself) could benefit from it. I was about to ignore this post until I paid a close attention to the suggested solution. Readers pay more attention to a solution when they see a green checkmark on it.

Comment: Thank you for providing this simple solution. I had spent hours on trying to customize a slider's ticks until I found this simple solution. I should have know better. This should be marked as an `Answer`.